# Extract email address from mysql field

Tags: mysql

I have a longtext column "description" in my table that sometimes contains an email address. I need to extract this email address and add to a separate column for each row. Is this possible to do in MySQL?

Comment: Of course yes. Please explain more what you have try so far and what is your database structure.

Comment: Basically, I have a "description" column and another column called "email" and I need to look for the email address in the description and add to the email column. I think I will write a quick Python script to do this, but was interested if there was a way to do it directly in the database.

Answer (score 5):

You can use substring index to capture email addresses...

The first substring index capture the account.
The second substring_index captures the hostname.  It is necessary to pick the same email address in case the are multiple atso (@) stored in the column.

```
select concat( substring_index(substring_index(description,'@',1),' ',-1)
             , substring_index(substring_index( description,
                                                substring_index(description,'@',1),-1),
                               ' ',1))
```

Answer (score 5):

Yes, you can use mysql's REGEXP (perhaps this is new to version 5 and 8 which may be after this question was posted.)

```
SELECT *, REGEXP_SUBSTR(`description`, '([a-zA-Z0-9._%+\-]+)@([a-zA-Z0-9.-]+)\.([a-zA-Z]{2,4})') AS Emails FROM `mytable`;
```

Answer (score 3):

You can't select matched part only from Regular expression matching using pure Mysql. You can use mysql extension (as stated in [Return matching pattern](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5361457/mysql-return-matching-pattern-in-regexp-query), or use a scripting language (ex. PHP).

Comment: @hd1 I was talking about matching (selecting the matched part only). You can't do this using pure mysql.

Answer (score 1):

MySQL **does** have [regular expressions](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/regexp.html), but regular expressions are not the best way to [match email addresses](http://www.regular-expressions.info/email.html). I'd strongly recommend using your client language.

Comment: of course you can match a regex, but you can't select the matched part only.

Comment: Which is why I *strongly recommended using your client language*

Answer (score 0):

If you can install the [`lib_mysqludf_preg`](https://github.com/mysqludf/lib_mysqludf_preg#lib_mysqludf_preg----preg-functions-for-mysql) MySQL UDF, then you could do:

```
SET @regex = "/([a-z0-9!#\$%&'\*\+\/=\?\^_`\{\|\}~\-]+(?:\.[a-z0-9!#\$%&'\*\+\/=\?^_`{\|}~\-]+)*@(?:[a-z0-9](?:[a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9])?\.)+(?:[A-Z]{2}|aero|arpa|asia|biz|cat|com|coop|edu|gov|info|int|jobs|mil|mobi|museum|name|net|org|post|pro|tel|travel|xxx))/i";

SELECT 
    PREG_CAPTURE(@regex, description) 
FROM 
    example 
WHERE
    PREG_CAPTURE(@regex, description) > '';
```

to extract the first email address from the `description` field.

I can't think of another solution, as the `REGEXP` operator simply returns 1 or 0, and not the location of where the regular expression matched.