# Is there a way to ORDER by REGEXP in MySQL statement?

Tags: mysql

what I have

```
SELECT CONCAT(`names`,' ',`office`) `bigDataField`
   FROM `item_table` 
HAVING `bigDataField` REGEXP "jessy|c";
```

returnes also Data which just contains letter "c" so I would like to ORDER BY most same matching characters, is that possible ?

NOTE: words and characters get changed by user input. So it can be only one character or a few or even a few words.

sql fiddle http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/dc87e/1

Thanks for all the help

Comment: What should be desired order? What is 'ORDER BY most same chars'?

Comment: @AlmaDo most same matching characters. I updated the question. Does that makes sense now?

Comment: order by length(bigdatafield) desc

Comment: @STTLCU something like that would be awesome, but does not change anything...http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/dc87e/13

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can order by any expression.

`regexp` returns the number of matches for the specified regex

So, this:

```
order by `bigDataField` regexp 'c' desc
```

will order your data by the `bigDataField` that has the most `c`'s in it as first so I guess it's not what you are looking for. You can use multiple `CASE-WHEN`s to check the length of the pattern matching (warning: bad performance - not recommended for big tables)

try this

```
SELECT CONCAT(`names`,' ',`office`) `bigDataField`, 
  CASE WHEN CONCAT(`names`,' ',`office`) regexp 'jessy' > 0 then length('jessy') * (CONCAT(`names`,' ',`office`) regexp 'jessy') ELSE 
      CASE WHEN CONCAT(`names`,' ',`office`) regexp 'c' > 0 then length('c') * (CONCAT(`names`,' ',`office`) regexp 'c') ELSE 0 END
  END as charmatchcount

FROM `item_table` 
HAVING `bigDataField` REGEXP "jessy|c"
ORDER BY charmatchcount desc
```

To avoid the above ugliness you must use an external library, or create your own function. You may find this thread helpful [MySQL - Return matching pattern in REGEXP query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5361457/mysql-return-matching-pattern-in-regexp-query)

Comment: thank you, I updated the question as I didn't mention this before. the string 'jessy|c' is made by user input so it changes and so the sql query has to change all the time. but thanks for the link, I will try with it

Comment: Then you can create the sql query in your server code (php or perl or whatever), otherwise see the link I posted.

Answer (score 1):

You can try with this

```
SELECT CONCAT(`names`,' ',`office`) `bigDataField`
       FROM `item_table` 
HAVING `bigDataField` REGEXP '[a-z] c' order by bigDataField asc;
```

Hope this will work for you

Comment: thanks for your answer but I don't see any ordering here. the REGEXP'value' gets changed by users, so it can be a few letters or a few words

Comment: you can use order by bigDataField asc;

Comment: but what if there are a few words and letters matching?

Comment: please see this link http://82.157.70.109/mirrorbooks/mysqlcrashcourse/0672327120/ch09lev1sec2.html

Answer (score 0):

this works:

```
SELECT col, IF( LOCATE('Jessy', col) = 0, 0 , LENGTH('Jessy')) as ord
FROM
(
SELECT CONCAT( `names`,' ',`office`) `col`
       FROM `item_table` 
HAVING `col` REGEXP "jessy|c"
) x
ORDER BY ord DESC;
```

but if there is 3 word in REGEXP, hard to find relevant query.

BTW are you looking for Full Text Search?

Comment: thanks, I updated the question as I didn't mention this before. the string 'jessy|c' is made by user input so it changes and so the sql query has to change all the time

Comment: @caramba then he or she can search by 'jessy|c|foo'? humm. I wonder if you integrate MySQL and Search Engine. please see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2271600/elasticsearch-sphinx-lucene-solr-xapian-which-fits-for-which-usage