# MySQL - search and trim all special characters

Tags: mysql, regex, special-characters

I would like to find all special characters which are used in 'mytable' > column 'name'

```
SELECT name 
FROM mytable 
WHERE name regexp '[^a-zA-Z0-9]'
```

But I would like to receive results which will not show whole 'name' data, but only this special character used in the column 'name'. How can I do it?

Comment: Bad news: there's no replace by regex in MySQL. So, use `REPLACE()` 26*2+10 times. Yes, it's horrible - so, yes, don't use DBMS for that, use your application

Comment: Check this package: https://github.com/hholzgra/mysql-udf-regexp

Comment: Duplicate of [MySQL - Return matching pattern in REGEXP query](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5361457/mysql-return-matching-pattern-in-regexp-query).

Comment: Check this post   [How to do a regular expression replace in MySQL?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/986826/1673391)

Comment: Ok, thanks. Just to be sure: I do not need to change (replace) special characters. I just want to receive the list of all special characters used in database