# Get distinct RegEx Matches on mySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, regex

I need some help from the RegEx and SQL nerds. ^^

I've a comment field in a table, which content looks like this:

What I need is a DISTINCT list of all user names - eg.

- b.willis
- p.fox
- g.clooney

  ```
  CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `comments` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `comment` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
   ) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 AUTO_INCREMENT=5 ;

  INSERT INTO `comments` (`id`, `comment`) VALUES
  (1, 'test [name](p.fox)[/name]'),
  (2, 'another test [name](p.fox)[/name]'),
  (3, 'lalala [name](b.willis)[/name]'),
  (4, 'lulu [name](g.clooney)[/name]');
  ```

Thx!

Comment: Why would you not have a separate field in the table for the name?

Comment: It's some kind of plugin for an existing system, which creates this 'trash' - so I've no choice...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way to approach this is using `substring_index()`.  Assuming each comment has this structure *and* only has one name:

```
select distinct substring_index(substring_index(comment, '[name](', 2), ')[/name]', 1) as name
from comments
```

Answer (score 0):

See the thread [MySQL - Return matching pattern in REGEXP query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5361457/mysql-return-matching-pattern-in-regexp-query)

Also check [How to do a regular expression replace in MySQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/986826/how-to-do-a-regular-expression-replace-in-mysql) and the referenced [UDF implementation of RegExp](https://github.com/hholzgra/mysql-udf-regexp). Take a look on the implementation of the UDF **REGEXP_SUBSTR**