# mysql: nicest way to say "the string up to the first instance of any of the following keywords"?

Tags: mysql, regex, locate

I can think of convoluted and ugly ways to do this in mysql but i'm looking for a nice way.  Let's say i have a bunch of school names, like

```
Meopham County Infant School
Speldhurst Nursery School
Rainbow Pre-School
The Annex School House
Fleet Learning Zone
Dartford Grammar School
Kiddliwinks
Hextable Kindergarten
The Rocking Horse Montessori Kinder
Little Angels Day Nursery
```

and i have a list of stopwords:

```
["school", "primary", "nursery", "college", "junior", "church", "cofe", "community", "infant"]
```

I have a ruby function "short_name" which returns the school name up to, **but not including**, the first instance of any of the stop words, so that we get

```
"Bower Grove School" => "Bower Grove"
"Fulston Manor School" => "Fulston Manor"
"St Johns Church Hall Play" => "St Johns"
"St Botolph's Church of England Voluntary Aided Primary School" => "St Botolph's"
"Fawkham House School" => "Fawkham House"
"Silverdale Day Nursery" => "Silverdale Day"
"Vigo Village School" => "Vigo Village"
"Sevenoaks Primary School" => "Sevenoaks"
"High Weald Academy" => "High Weald Academy"
"The Ebbsfleet Academy" => "The Ebbsfleet Academy"
```

That's all fine.  My question is:  what's the simplest way to do the above string processing in mysql?

eg, if i wanted to search by this short_name, i'd want to do something like

```
"select * from schools where <function(name)> = 'Bower Grove'"
```

what's the simplest way to do `<function>`?  I'd thought that some combination of substring(), and locate(), using a regex, would be the way to go, but it looks like i can't use a regex with locate.

I guess the regex would be

```
"school|primary|nursery|college|junior|church|cofe|community|infant"
```

thanks, Max

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5361457/mysql-return-matching-pattern-in-regexp-query

Comment: Thanks @Taemyr, i'd prefer to avoid a solution which requires a patch to MySQL if possible.  Appreciate the option though :)

Comment: Have you considered using a LIKE clause at all? `SELECT * FROM schools WHERE name LIKE 'Bower Grove%';` would return all schools where the name starts with the string `Bower Grove`.

Comment: I need to use the function in an update, as well as a select, so that's not an option i'm afraid.  Also, that would return schools called eg "Bower Grove Park" as well as "Bower Grove".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

MySQL does support regular expressions.  Unfortunately, it is only used for matching.

Here is one method:

```
select least(substring_index(schoolname, ' School', 1),
             substring_index(schoolname, ' Primary', 1),
             . . .
            )
```

This uses `substring_index()` to extract the first part of a string before the separator.  If the separator is not present, you get the whole string.  The `least()` function will then choose the shortest string.

This assumes that that keyword has a space before it.  After all, you probably don't want to totally eliminate everything for a name like "School for Little Angels".

Comment: That's great, thanks Gordon.  `substring_index()` is case sensitive (i assumed the solution would be case insensitive since mysql usually is, by default) but i got round this by starting with the titleized stopwords ("Primary", "School" etc) and generating substring_index functions for both versions and adding them to the list.